# null is not an object when calling react-native camera roll

Tags: react-native, camera-roll

I'm using the @react-native-community/cameraroll library to upload a video from the camera roll. For this, I'm using the getPhotos function. Using this function, however, is causing the following error:

```
null is not an object (evaluating '_nativeInterface.default.getPhotos')
```

I'm calling the getPhotos function as follows:

```
<Pressable onPress={() => {
          CameraRoll.getPhotos({first:10});
          }}
        style={({ pressed }) => [{
            backgroundColor: pressed ? 'white' : '#03befc'
        },
    styles.upload]}>
            <Text style={styles.uploadText}>Upload Video</Text></Pressable>
```

What's wrong with calling the camera roll like I've called it in the onPress event of the Pressable component that it's giving me the error that I mention?

Yes, I have added the keys and strings

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Our application needs permission to write photos...</string>
  <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
  <string>Our application needs permission to write photos...</string>
```

But I'm still getting the error.

Comment: What's your device?

Comment: iPhone 11 simulator

Comment: Did you gave it permission?

Comment: How to give it permission?

Comment: In the `Info.plist` file

Comment: Yes, I have added the keys and strings

<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Our application needs permission to write photos...</string>
  <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
  <string>Our application needs permission to write photos...</string>
But I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Did you run `pod install`?

Comment: After running pod install, I'm getting the prompt that asks for access to all photos, clicking which doesn't open the camera roll :(

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-cameraroll/react-native-cameraroll/issues/113 did you checked this forum?

Comment: This isn't the problem. The problem is that nothing is loaded.

Comment: Are you using expo?

Comment: Just checked the source code of cameraroll. It is definitely a problem with your local setup, as the lib can't find the native module for the camera lib. This usually means that something during installation went wrong. After pod install you have to rebuild the app (react-native run-ios). Also, if you are using a react native version below 0.60 you need to manually link the library. Is that the case for you?

Comment: No I'm using the latest version of react native and I did run pod isntall

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the js context not with the code. Try adding a **return** in front of your function calling, it might solve the issue.

```
<Pressable onPress={() => {
         return CameraRoll.getPhotos({first:10});
          }}
        style={({ pressed }) => [{
            backgroundColor: pressed ? 'white' : '#03befc'
        },
    styles.upload]}>
            <Text style={styles.uploadText}>Upload Video</Text></Pressable>
```